# Rewrite rule to handle urls that start with a slash, have only numbers and letters, and may end with a slash is not working

Tags: php, htaccess, centos

im attempting to get my URL to resolve something like

```
http://example.com/?image=2VMt2
```

Thus my index.php using the [GET] method in PHP to resolve into my domain

```
http://example.com/2VMt2
```

The rule I am using is stated below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?image=$1    [NC,L]
```

Im running CentOS and my Configuration looks something like the following.

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/var/www/html">

# 
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
# 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
# 
    AllowOverride All

# 
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server configuration seems to be correct.

But you need to modify your mod_rewrite code. Remove leading `/` and make trailing slash optional by using `/?$` in rewrite rule, so both `http://example.com/2VMt2` and `http://example.com/2VMt2/` URLs will work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?image=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was completing the .htaccess in the wrong folder in my previous comment, haha.

Comment: (I assume the `^^` and `$$` is a copy/paste typo?) In fact, if this is in .htaccess then the preceding `/` can simply be removed. Also, if you are substituting a relative path then you should use a `RewriteBase` directive, or better, don't use relative paths.

Comment: @w3d no it's not a typo. But you are right, the preceding `/` isn't actually required here.

Comment: So... if it's not a typo, it's a _deliberate_ mistake?

Comment: no, the code still works, as both `/` are optional. I've edited the answer and removed the leading `/` and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In terms of the "typo/mistake", I was really just querying the doubling of the placeholder markers `^^` and `$$`. Whilst this would "still work", it unnecessarily complicates the regex and just makes the parser work harder.

Comment: but `/?$` is required here. without it `example.com/2VMt2` and `example.com/2VMt2/` won't work at a time.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I'm querying. I'm saying that `/?$$` should be `/?$`, the additional `$` is not necessary (and complicates the regex). (Just like the two `^` at the start of the regex were not necessary, but you removed one of them when you removed the `/?` - at the start.)

Comment: ohh.. now I understand. You are right `$$` is also not required, single `$` is enough here. Thanks again for pointing that out.